# Couldn't find Timesheet without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I grouped some Timesheet objects together using activerecord

```
scope :grouped_by_user_with_total_time, lambda {
  group(:user_id, :day).select('user_id, SUM(time_worked) AS time_total, day, editable, approvable, accepted, comments')
}
```

And after I did that, now when I try to call the approve method on the grouped objects I get the error

```
Couldn't find TimeSheet without an ID
```

And it highlights the third line in my method

```
def approve
if params[:time_sheets]
@time_sheets = []
*t = TimeSheet.find(params[:time_sheets])**  
if t.instance_of?(Array)
  @time_sheets = t
else
  @time_sheets << t
end
successful = []
unsuccessful = []

@time_sheets.each do |timesheet|
  unless timesheet.approved
    timesheet.approve
    if timesheet.save
      successful << timesheet
    else
      unsuccessful << timesheet
    end
  end
end
end
```

I'm not very experienced with activerecord and am curious how the grouping effects the methods, and what I need to do so that the methods can go from before where they just took the individual objects, to where the methods will work on all of the grouped objects.

Comment: What is in your `params` hash? And what's the connection between the `grouped_by_user_with_total_time` scope and the TimeSheet.find call - it doesn't look like the scope is used at all in the code you've pasted.

Comment: Are you sure `params[:time_sheets]` is not nil?

Comment: How do I know if it's nil?

Comment: Look at your logs, add `puts params` to `#approve` or use the indispensable pry interactive debugger (you'd add `binding.pry` somewhere before the offending line and check the value of `params[:time_sheets]`).

Comment: Ok, I think that was it so I fixed it by adding an if statement (just edited to show it.). But now i'm getting `undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass`